# ASP.NET ApiController supported request content types with Consumes Attribute not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, controller, swagger, content-type

I'm trying to accept `multipart/form-data` and `application/json` content type within the same URL endpoint with Consumes Attribute like in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#define-supported-request-content-types-with-the-consumes-attribute

```
private IActionResult CreateQuestion(QuestionCreateDto question)
{
    // some logic
}

[HttpPost("questions")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public IActionResult CreateQuestionJson(QuestionCreateDto question)
{
    return CreateQuestion(question);
}

[HttpPost("questions")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public IActionResult CreateQuestionForm([FromForm] QuestionCreateDto question)
{
    return CreateQuestion(question);
}
```

but swagger UI wont let me and gives the following error:

> SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "POST api/questions" for actions -
> [MyProject].Controllers.QuestionController.CreateQuestionJson (MyProject), [MyProject].Controllers.QuestionController.CreateQuestionForm (MyProject).
> Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0.
> Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround

Did I miss something from the docs? Is there any workaround so that I can make an endpoint to accept two different content type?

Comment: Hi, this looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/390#issuecomment-442120145), and we might only test with tool like postman, because the API worked well while SwaggerUI reported failure. Or change the route name when test in SwaggerUI, and change route name back when need to publish.